# Why does .NET MVC 4 take the value from the GET query string instead of the model binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following .cshtml code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BeginDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "datefield" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EndDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "datefield" })
```

By using POST, the values displayed are correct(also because I am using a model binder)

However, if I use GET (I am using PagedList.Mvc), and I create the following query: `Index?page=3&beginDate=2015-07-01&endDate=2015-07-06`, the following values are displayed in the textboxes: 2015-07-01 and 2015-07-06, instead of 01.07.2015 and 06.07.2015.

But If I change the parameters names to `Index?page=3&iBeginDate=2015-07-01&iEndDate=2015-07-06`, the values are displayed correctly in the textboxes (01.07.2015 and 06.07.2015).

My headers for my GET and POST methods are the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int page = 1, int? workCenterId = null, DateTime? beginDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null, int? shiftId = null)
{
    var model = GetModel(page: page, workCenterId: workCenterId, beginDate: beginDate, endDate: endDate, shiftId: shiftId);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(ReportModelBinder))]ReportModel model)
{
     var newModel = GetModel(model);
     return View(newModel);
}
```

Why does MVC prefer the GET parameters over the ones that are sent via the model ?

Comment: It is by design. The only way is to make sure your GET parameter does not conflict with your form (POST) parameter.

Comment: So there is no way to override this ?

Comment: Nop. Not that I know of.

Comment: If "model" is the same,  "return View(model);" should return exactly the same in the two actions... what type are your's model BeginDate property? string or Date? If it is string maybe is differently encoded previoulsy.

Comment: It's DateTime data type

Answer (score 1):

There isnt a preference, the action that is called is based on the request method (GET/POST etc) and action name, the default model binder will use value providers to get values for parameters and model properties, these values will come from the query string, form values, cookies, route data etc.

Comment: Do you have any documentation I could read about this ?

I could really use some examples.